# Can Marco the Phoenix regenerate a whole limb?

Tags: one-piece

Oda said that Marco's regeneration is limited, and we see him with bandages after war, but he has all of his limbs intact.

Can Marco the Phoenix regenerate a whole limb?

Answer (score 1):

It is too soon to tell. Oda has confirmed that Marco will be returning and his power more thoroughly explained. All we know about it now is that he has the Phoenix's

> "blue flame of revival"

however, Oda did not explain this in detail. Personally, I wouldn't think it impossible. Oda does say in the same breath:

> "In other words, the flames are for regeneration"

POSSIBLY implying that the limit to his regeneration is the fact that the flames have to be present. Maybe preventing those flames from being there could prevent any regeneration on Marco's part. Maybe if he is killed too quickly and doesn't have a chance to regenerate, there would be no hope from that point. But like I said before it is too soon to know for sure and at Ace and Whitebeards' funeral, we did see him in bandages (manga ep. 590, anime ep. 505). Hope that was helpful and check my Oda facts [here](http://otakukart.com/animeblog/2018/01/08/piece-creator-confirms-return-spoiler/).